# Allow user to Fill multiple Form fields continuously

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

I have the following field in my form, where a user should enter a 10 digit number.

I present the number in 3 separate fields (3-3-4):

`Phone: [_ _ _]-[_ _ _]-[_ _ _ _]`

Code:

```
     <div id="phone-element" class="form-element">
       <input type="tel" size="3" name="phone1" id="phone1" maxlength="3" tabindex="3" pattern="[0-9]{3}" title="3 digit phone number. Eg.808" required=""> <span class="wc_sep">-</span>
       <input type="tel" size="3" name="phone2" id="phone2" maxlength="3" tabindex="4" pattern="[0-9]{3}" title="3 digit phone number. Eg.789" required=""> <span class="wc_sep">-</span>
        <input type="tel" size="4" name="phone3" id="phone3" tabindex="5" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4" title="4 digit phone number. Eg.1374" required="">
      </div>
```

But currently between each field, users need to place their mouse in the next field in order to continue to type the number.

How can I make it continuously?

Comment: The best you can do here is to use _one_ input field; users know how those work. Any fancy JS stuff that makes the focus jump from one field to the next and similar just decreases usability. Modern browsers allow form prefilling with values the user entered in their settings; if you were to ask for my phone number, but then used such a construct that would make this fail - that'd be a UX fail as well. Or perhaps I have the phone number copy&paste ready - again, you would have to jump through a lot of hoops with JS to make that work properly with such needlessly ripped apart input fields.

Comment: I guess I should think about it. I just think maybe its more "neat" this way and will encourage users to fill it. how does browser auto fill works btw? when testing on my current code, autofill works fine even though all 3 fields are splitted. does it work beacuse the id is `phone-element`? beacuse in the css / js I don't have any setting for this id, don't know why the prtogrammer called it this way, unless it has to do with auto-fill.

Comment: There's "normal" autofill, based on data previously entered in form fields of the same name; and then there's autofill based on browser settings (where users can input their personal data, such as name, email, phone, ...), where the browser tries to find appropriate fields for the data based on field names. (Google has some info on how to name fields for that here, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with jQuery by checking the `length` of the entered value(on keyup) against the `maxlength` you have set on the inputs. If the `length` of the input value matches the `maxlength` of the input, then `focus` the next input:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="tel"]').keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length === this.maxLength) {
      $(this).nextAll('input[type="tel"]').first().focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="phone-element" class="form-element">
    <input type="tel" size="3" name="phone1" id="phone1" maxlength="3" tabindex="3" pattern="[0-9]{3}" title="3 digit phone number. Eg.808" required="">
    <span class="wc_sep">-</span>
    <input type="tel" size="3" name="phone2" id="phone2" maxlength="3" tabindex="4" pattern="[0-9]{3}" title="3 digit phone number. Eg.789" required="">
    <span class="wc_sep">-</span>
    <input type="tel" size="4" name="phone3" id="phone3" tabindex="5" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4" title="4 digit phone number. Eg.1374" required="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use JavaScript.

Attach an event listener to the input elements on `keyup`.  If the length of the field matches your predetermined length, add focus to the next input element.

e.g.

```
var phone1 = document.getElementById('phone1');
phone1.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if (phone1.value.length === 3) {
       document.getElementById('phone2').focus();
    }
});
```

You might need to cater to any edge cases that you find to make sure the UX is smooth, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta content="">
    <style></style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="" id="field1">
    <input type="text" name="" id="field2">
    <input type="text" name="" id="field3">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        var field1 = $("#field1");
        var field2 = $("#field2");
        var field3 = $("#field3");
        field1.on("keyup", function(e){
            if(field1.val().length == 3)
            {
                field2.focus();
            }
        })

        field2.on("keyup", function(e){
            if(field2.val().length == 3)
            {
                field3.focus();
            }
        })
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This can be simplified quite a bit, no reason to specify different events for each individual input.